# Laravel form model attributes

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

How to pass attributes like `id`, `class` to form model?

This what i try not working and in official Laravel documentation wass not defined.

```
@if(isset($country))
    {{ Form::model($country, ['route' => ['country.show', $country->id]], ['class' => "123"]) }}
@else
    {{ Form::open(['route' => 'country.store', 'id'=> 'admin_store_form' ]) }}
@endif
 <div class="row mb-2">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        {{ Form::label('name', 'Name', ['class' => 'col-sm-2 admin-label col-form-label']) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        {{ Form::text('name', old('name'), ['placeholder'=>'Name', 'class' => 'form-control form-control-sm admin-control']) }}
    </div>
</div>
 
{{ Form::close() }}
```

I define `'class' => "123"` but that not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to add a class to `Form::model` is:

```
{{ Form::model($country, ['route' => ['country.show', $country->id], 'class' => '123']) }}
```

You need to add the `class` key to the same array argument as `route`.

Comment: Thanks it work. I dont know whay official documentation not write.